# expected 'letters_t' {aka 'struct <anonymous>'} but argument is of type 'letters_t *' {aka 'struct <anonymous> *'}

Tags: c, function, structure

I am working on using a structure in a function, but when I try to run the code I get this error:

note: expected 'pixels_t' {aka 'struct '} but argument is of type 'pixels_t *' {aka 'struct  *'}

Here is my code:

```
typedef struct{
        unsigned int a, b, c;
}letters_t;

void fillLetterArray(letters_t letters);

int main (void){
letters_t letterArray[100];
fillLetterArray(letterArray);
}

void fillLetterArray(letters_t letters){

}
```

Thank you in advance for the answer.

Comment: `letterArray` is an array of 100 `letters_t` objects. The `fillLetterArray` only expects one object so you need to pass only one of them. Example: `fillLetterArray(letterArray[0]);`

Comment: Or change the function to accept an array: `void fillLetterArray(letters_t letters[])` - which probably makes more sense based on the name.

Comment: Identifiers ending with `_t` are [reserved by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02_02)

Answer (score 1):

Your function takes structure, but your main program wants to pass pointer to the structure. You need to change this function accordingly:

```
void fillLetterArray(letters_t *letters);

int main (void)
{
   letters_t letterArray[100];
   fillLetterArray(letterArray);
}

void fillLetterArray(letters_t *letters)
{
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you abstain from (ab)using `typedef` without a good reason, it's meant to create abstractions, and there's no advantage in this context.

If the intention is to fill an array, as the name implies, then the function `fillLetterArray` needs to take a pointer to the array; additionally, it's a good idea to include the length of the array in a parameter:

```c
#include <stdint.h> // for size_t

struct letters {
        unsigned int a, b, c;
};

static void fillLetterArray(struct letters *letters, size_t length);

int main (void) {
    struct letters_t letterArray[100];
    fillLetterArray(letterArray, 100);
}

void fillLetterArray(struct letters *letters, size_t length) {
    ...
}
```